# Change Column's Ordinal Position

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

Is it possible to change a column's ordinal position in regard to cdc output?

I see documentation on [cdc.captured_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-captured-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) here and that table contains a "column_ordinal" column. I can't find any documentation on whether this column can be used to override how the columns lay in cdc storage and transport.

Comment: As per normal tables, column order can't be altered except by recreating the table. In this case that would mean dropping and recreating the CDC capture. It seems unwise to rely in any way on the ordering of columns there (just as in regular tables you'd be ill-advised to rely on the order of a `SELECT *`), and there seems to be no good reason to -- you can specify a custom order when you select the CDC data from the `fn_get_*_changes` functions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Thanks for the reply. The data is being replicated from many databases via cdc and read in by a cloud service. Most of the tables in each database have the exact same structure, however, some of the older databases have column ordinality differences. Those differences can't be handled by the cloud services. Just trying to find the path of least resistance.

Comment: "Those differences can't be handled by the cloud services" - This is because n databases are being migrated into one cloud database. It appears that the incoming data payloads have to match the target schema's column ordinality.

Comment: Silly design is silly. Typically you pay $$$ for those services, you could try raising the issue with their support. Alternatively, if they offer some form of ELT other than directly connecting to CDC, you could build something inbetween that does the translating. Alternatively, recreate CDC manually with the desired column order, though this may require some jiggery-pokery to sync things up again.

Comment: Maybe you can use another solution, change tracking is more flexible where you only need to track your PKs and manually build data that was changed. Or could you create views which mirrors correct column names to your local dbs but point to "wrong" columns in the "cloud" table and change capture into those views instead?